# Url Rewriting Silex

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, silex

I'm building a project with the micro framework **Silex**, on my localhost
I'm using Apache 2.2.22
Here is the structure:

```
/var/www/ProjectName/
    vendor/
    web/
        .htaccess
        index.php
```

In my .htacces there is:

```
 FallbackResource /index.php
```

The homepage works perfectly, but when I try to go to a page that requires URL rewriting, I got a 404.
Here is the code for the second controller:

```
$app->get('/view/{token}', function (Request $request, $token) use ($app, $db) {
    echo 'ok';exit;

    return $app['twig']->render('home.twig.html');
})
->bind('view');
```

What do i do wrong ?

Comment: are you using apache 2.2.16 ? are you querying from localhost or a subpath ? what is your webroot , web folder ?

Comment: Well, I am not a silex expert but the error could come from your controller. Your `return` statement can never be hit since you run a `exit` before. So your `bind()` call might not work as expected...

Comment: Did you try without the leading `/` in your FallbackResource directive?

Comment: I'm using apache 2.2.22. 
The webroot is at /var/www

and the project is in /var/www/ProjectName/web

I know but i've also tried without the echo and it doesn't work either. With the exit, it should still display the content of the action. The binding works, I can create a url by call {{ path('view') }} in the twig template

yes i did try this, and it didn't work :(

Comment: What URL did you try that gave you the 404?

Comment: I tried localhost/ProjectName/view/randomtoken

Comment: Did you try http://localhost/view/randomtoken

Comment: i'll try, but i doubt it'll work since the localhost/ProjectName/ url is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, it had nothing to do with Silex.
I simply forgot to change the directive
AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The webroot is at **/var/www** and the project is in /var/www/ProjectName/**web**

and

> I tried localhost/ProjectName/view/randomtoken

You should access your project with

> localhost/ProjectName/**web**/view/randomtoken